# Cannot parse DateTime object from date string with country and daylight time

Tags: javascript, datetime, luxon

I cannot parse this string as a `DateTime` object with `luxon`. It always comes back as invalid.

```
Thu Feb 23 2023 16:00:00 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
```

It hasnt worked with any of these `fromISO, fromHTTP, fromRFC28822` so I suspect it should be converted into another format first.

Comment: You can use `.fromFormat()` and feed it something that matches your strings, or (preferably) fix whatever is generating those string and use ISO instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime('Thu Feb 23 2023 16:00:00 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)').fromJSDate()` worked.